# Freezing all dependencies when building executables with `cabal v2-install`

Tags: haskell, cabal, cabal-install, cabal-new

I am building a Docker image in which I want to bundle multiple executables. Each executable is defined in a different package, in my case `pandoc`, `pandoc-citeproc`, and `pandoc-crossref`. The build should be as reproducible as reasonably possible on a Debian/Ubuntu based system.

What I'd like to do is use (something like) a *cabal.project.freeze* file to ensure that all subsequent builds will use the same packages.

I'm aware that I can fix the version of the executables:

```
cabal v2-install pandoc-2.7.3 pandoc-citeproc-0.16.2 pandoc-crossref-0.3.4.1
```

But this will not fix the versions of transitive dependencies, so rebuilding at different times may lead to subtly different build results. Can I somehow create and use a *freeze* file in this setup?  Using v2-freeze seems to be of no use here:

```
$ cabal new-freeze pandoc-2.7.3 pandoc-citeproc-0.16.2 pandoc-crossref-0.3.4.1
cabal: 'freeze' doesn't take any extra arguments: pandoc-2.7.3
pandoc-citeproc-0.16.2 pandoc-crossref-0.3.4.1
```

Comment: There is a command literally called [`v2-freeze`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/nix-local-build.html#cabal-v2-freeze), which creates a file with exactly the name and behavior you propose...

Comment: @DanielWagner That's exactly my problem: I don't see how I could use that here.

Comment: Ah, I understand the issue now: you want a freeze file, but without creating a project.

Comment: You forgot about cabal revisions, even if you pin the exact version at any point in the future cabal file can change and your pinned version might no longer work

Comment: My suggestion is use `stack`, this is the only way to truly pin all of the dependencies (including transitive ones) that are guaranteed to work now and any point in the future. Even if you use dependencies from outside hackage you can pin them by content addressable hash value, which will guarantee that the dependency does not change from under you.

Comment: Docker images are never 100% reproducible, if you use the regular `Dockerfile` way of building them. However, `nix` can build images directly and those are 100% reproducible. They're also more compact. If you pin the version of `nixpkgs` to a particular git commit, you have a 100% reproducible build forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, there might be a better built-in way to do this kind of thing, but here's a hacky workaround that might be suitable for you until a real cabal expert comes along.

The basic plan will be this: temporarily create a project with the three packages you care about -- just long enough to get a freeze file -- then use some simple text-editor macros to turn the freeze file into a `v2-install` command. So:

```
% cabal unpack pandoc-2.7.3 pandoc-citeproc-0.16.2 pandoc-crossref-0.3.4.1
% echo >cabal.project packages: pandoc-2.7.3 pandoc-citeproc-0.16.2 pandoc-crossref-0.3.4.1
% cabal v2-freeze
% sed "s/^constraints: /cabal v2-install pandoc-2.7.3 pandoc-citeproc-0.16.2 pandoc-crossref-0.3.4.1 --constraint '/;s/^ \+/--constraint '/;s/,\$/' \\\\/;\$s/\$/'/" cabal.project.freeze >cabal-v2-install.sh
```

Woof, that last one is a mouthful. It says:

```
# Replace the starting "constraints" stanza with the v2-install command we want to
# run. The first line of the stanza includes a constraint, so prefix it with
# --constraint and start a quote.
s/^constraints: /cabal v2-install pandoc-2.7.3 pandoc-citeproc-0.16.2 pandoc-crossref-0.3.4.1 --constraint '/
# The line we just produced doesn't start with spaces, so this only fires on the
# remaining lines. On those lines, it prefixes --constraint and starts a quote.
s/^ \+/--constraint '/
# Close the quote begun on each line, and replace cabal's line-continuation
# character (,) with a shell's line-continuation character (\). The $ and \ are
# escaped because we are inside the current shell's ""-quoted string.
s/,\$/' \\\\/
# The last line doesn't have a line-continuation character, but still needs its
# quote closed. The two occurrences of $ are escaped because we are inside the
# current shell's ""-quoted string.
\$s/\$/'/
```

You could also do these manually in an editor if you wanted. At the end of this process, which you can run in a temporary directory to ease cleanup afterwards, you should have a file named `cabal-v2-install.sh` with a command that will select the exact same versions and flags for all packages involved, including dependencies.

Comment: It's really hacky, but makes perfect sense. Thanks for this! :D